# Where to get previous versions of iOS disk image?

Tags: iphone, ios

I just became a member of iOS Developer Program and I'm reading the document iOS Developer Program User Guide. It says:

1. Download the iOS Disk Image (.dmg) from the iOS Dev Center for the Apple device you are using.

Well, in my Xcode Organizer, I can see two versions: 4.2.1(8C148) and 4.3.2(8H7). Suppose I want to test my application on previous version of iOS, say 4.0 or 3.x. Where can I find/download the iOS Disk Image(firmware) as the document says?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean the firmware's IPSW ? Google has some good results:

http://www.iphoneheat.com/2009/03/download-iphone-firmware-files-all-at-one-place/

Comment: Note that Apple makes difficult to restore old firmwares... Some "hackery" might be involved to do so...

Comment: old iOS can allow new Xcode to develop app for older iOS versions.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has made it difficult to downgrade firmwares on iOS devices. Once you upgrade past 4.2.x (I think), you may not be able to go back. Nonetheless, you might go [here for older firmwares](http://leimobile.com/firmware-downloads/).