# Is it possible to downgrade from iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

On the Apple developer site, it states that "Devices updated to iOS 5 beta can not be restored to earlier versions of iOS." I believe this is new, and remember seeing that Apple is changing the way it provides older versions of iOS. I'd like to be able to install iOS 5, knowing that I can revert to iOS 4 if need be, since I have some apps that may not be compatible.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, A) is it hard, and B), does it actually violate Apple's TOS?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, but not on topic for SO.  Best place to ask would be Apple's [devforums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios)

Comment: Check this related question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692631/where-to-get-previous-versions-of-ios-disk-image

Answer (score 1):

Apple has repeatedly said that there is no officially supported way to downgrade from iOS beta OS versions.  Don't play with beta OS versions except on test devices which you don't need for running apps that may not be compatible with the beta OS.  e.g. you need a spare device to temporarily trash.